# Как вывести результат в одну переменную?

Tags: php

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть код:

```
$string = "Если вы поставите перед собой абсурдно высокие цели, и это обернется неудачей, ваша неудача будет выше успеха всех остальных.";

    if (strpos($string, "цели") !== false) {echo "цель";}
    if (strpos($string, "успеха") !== false) {echo "успех";}
    if (strpos($string, "усердность") !== false) {echo "усердие";}
    
    return $result;
```

Задача, чтобы результат был в одной переменной $result, через запятую, а echo нужно убрать. Т.е. получиться должно так:

```
// Вывод: цель, успех
```

Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = "Если вы поставите перед собой абсурдно высокие цели, и это обернется неудачей, ваша неудача будет выше успеха всех остальных.";
$strArray = [];

if (strpos($string, "цели") !== false) {
    $strArray[] = 'цели';
}
if (strpos($string, "успеха") !== false) {
    $strArray[] = 'успеха';
}
if (strpos($string, "усердность") !== false) {
    $strArray[] = 'усердность';
}

return implode(", ", $strArray);
```

Я не совсем понял ваш вопрос, но возможно вам пригодится оператор слияния строк `.=`

Comment: Как всё просто с `.=` . Спасибо большое.

Comment: @InDevX ну да, вы правы в целом. Написал на скорую руку без тестирования, из головы вылетел `implode`. Отредактировал ответ.